# CActiveDataProvider with a regular non-database array

Tags: php, arrays, yii, pagination, cactivedataprovider

I have an array of $items in Yii application which I want to paginate. The array is not related to the database so there's no condition to consider here, just a bunch of defined items that I need to display. So I'm trying to use the CActiveDataProvider like this:

```
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($items, array(
            'pagination' => array(
                'PageSize' => 10,
            ) 
        ));

        $this->renderPartial('view', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

Then in the view I'm trying to display the information:

```
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
      ));
```

I get a `Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object` fatal error which is totally understandable since my $items array is customized and not database related so my question is how can I go around this issue and is it even possible using the CActiveDataProvider?

If it's not, is there another way to create a pagination for a custom non-database related array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) for this case.

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($items, array(
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

Comment: Never noticed there were to classes - Active & Array. Thank you!